# Error in stored procedure with Firebird database

Tags: firebird

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will take a string of 50 bytes and scan though it one byte at a time looking for commas. Once found I want to update a field and then continue scanning the string to look for additional commas.

I am using a Firebird database and using `DBVisualizer` to develop the code.

```
@delimiter ++;

CREATE PROCEDURE scan_for_comma(
       lastname_field CHAR(50),
       sr_bold_id     int
 )
 RETURNS (
    comma_flag varchar(1))
    AS
 declare variable   max_bytes inv default 50;
 declare variable I integer;

 BEGIN
 I = 0;
 While 
  (I <= max_bytes)
  DO
  Begin
  if (substring(name_field from I for 1) = ',') then
     Begin
       comma_flag = 'Y'
       I = I +1
       UPDATE sr_address
       SET lastname = (substring(name_field from i for 1) = ' ')
       WHERE bold_id   = :sr_bold_id
     end     
  ELSE 
     (substring(name_field from loop_cnt for 1) != ',') then
      Begin
      I = I +1
      END
  END
END
++
@delimiter ;++
```

I get this error

> 14:45:34  [@DELIMITER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]
>   Command processed
>   14:45:34  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]
>   [Error Code: 335544569, SQL State: HY000]
>   GDS Exception. 335544569.
>   Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 21, column 12 
>   14:45:34 [@DELIMITER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]
>   Command processed ...
>   3 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec
>   [2 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is "loop_cnt"? Is it variable? Then where it is declared and where is set?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know DBVisualizer, but I would try syntax:

```
set term ++ ;

create procedure ...
:
end ++

set term ; ++
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a suspend command to return rows.
Example:

```
comma_flag = 'Y';
suspend; -- returns a row
```

Answer (score 0):

In expression

```
  ...
  ELSE 
     (substring(name_field from loop_cnt for 1) != ',') then
  ...
```

missing keyword **IF** after ELSE

Answer (score 0):

In ISQL it isn't @delimiter, but SET TERM, however this is only about ISQL and some other tools (eg FlameRobin).

However, the use of SET TERM is not specific to Firebird itself (the database engine itself does not know that command). Most likely you don't need to specify the delimiter in this tool. Just don't use a delimiter after the `END` of the procedure.